# OpenGL/GLEW: How to choose the correct/existing enum without provoking a compile time error

Tags: opengl, enums, glew

I am currently using glew to detect some GPU features of the bound openGL context.

Imagine a texture class where I want to use the openGL 3.0 enums if available and fallback to extensions if opengl 3.0 is not in place but the extension is i.e:

```
uint32 chooseGlInternalFormat(uint32 _pixelType, uint32 _pixelFormat)
{
    uint32 ret;
    //...
    if(GLEW_EXT_texture_integer || GLEW_VERSION_3_0)
    {
        bool bUseExt = !GLEW_VERSION_3_0; //if only the extension is available but not gl 3.0, fallback
        ret = bUseIntEXT ? GL_LUMINANCE8UI_EXT : GL_R8UI;
    }
    //...
}
```

obviously this causes a compile time error since `GL_R8UI` won't exist if opengl 3.0 is not supported.- What is the common way to solve this?

Comment: Why doesn't that work?  IIRC, those macros expand to run-time function calls (or else global variables filled in by `glewInit`).  Whereas the enums are always provided by the header file.

Comment: well for instance I currently develop on OSX which does not support complete ogl 3.0 functionlity.- Still I want to take that in to account for future use.- Now that on my platform ogl 3.0 is not complete some of it's enums are simply not defined, thus causing a compile time error. in the example above GL_R8UI is not defined.

Comment: @moka: Having the enums in your headers doesn't hurt, no matter if OpenGL-3 is provided by your target plattform or not. Also plattform specific codepath adjustments are implemented through conditional compilation, i.e. `#ifdef … {foobarblah;} #endif`; GLEW sets several defines, depending on which features are enabled at compilation time. Those are set depending on what the target platform can do.

Comment: okay, lets say, I want to use glGenerateMipmap on ogl 3.0 and later and glGenerateMipmapEXT on all earlier version.- What would be a reliable compile time check to use the correct function? the comments on pmr's answer indicate that #ifdef GL_VERSION_3_0  is not working in most cases, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some larger applications take the [newest enum specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/enum.spec) and add their own enums based on it. If you only need it this one time you can just define your own enum for this single case.

Comment: wouldnt those enums conflict with the ones that actually are allready there if opengl 3.x exists?

Comment: @moka You need to give them different names of course. What is important are the values, not the names.

Comment: ah ok I think I get it now. Another thing I just realized is that even though GLEW only works at run time I can use plain old #ifdef GL_VERSION_3_0 preprocessor defines to include stuff only if a certain GL version is reached. Thanks for your hints!

Comment: The preprocessor is not an option should you try to distribute binaries and the code is painful and hard to test/debug. That's why most projects prefer the hacky workaround.

Comment: could you clearify why the GL_VERSION_3_0 define would not work on a binary if used inside a .cpp?

Comment: @moka Because the preprocessor is only triggered when the application is compiled but the GL version of the platform the binary is executed on can only be determined at runtine.

Comment: @moka: You can use the preprocessor to detect the SDK you're building with, like `#ifdef GL_R8UI`, but don't test `#ifdef GL_VERSION_3_0`, since that will always be defined, it expands to a runtime test.

Comment: good idea ben, do you think if i do this for all the formats i need: #ifndef GL_RGB8UI
#define GL_RGB8UI GL_RGB8UI_EXT
#endif would be safe? then i could only use GL_RGB8UI in my actual code and if would automatically fall back to GL_RGB8UI_EXT if needed right?